# How to find two numbers in array with JS

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to find two numbers whose multiplication result is 6

Comment: Is array sorted ? Can it have negative numbers ?

Comment: Can you show us what algorithm you have tried?

Comment: The array is not sorted and has only positive numbers.

Comment: Will the array ever have numbers greater than the multiplication result?

Comment: I want to try two loops which checking if item[1] and item[2] are appropriate

Comment: Yes, array may have numbers greater than the multiplication result

Comment: And do you want to exit the loop after finding a given pair, or do you want to find all pairs?

Comment: I want to exit after finding a given pair

Comment: And the array may have duplicate numbers

Comment: @IvanCh added solution. kindly verify

Comment: thank all of you very much. All your solutions are good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like as

```
 function foo(arr, res) {
let numbers = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
  for (let k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k ++) {
    if (arr[i] * arr[k] === res) {
      return [...numbers, arr[i], arr[k]]
    }
  }
}
  return([...numbers])
  }
```

console.log(foo([2, 3, 4, 5], 6))

Answer (score 2):

This prints all pairs of numbers in the list whose product equals 6.

```js
const list = [2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i+1; j < list.length; j++) {
    if (list[i] * list[j] == 6) {
      console.log(list[i] + ' * ' + list[j] + ' = 6');
    }
  }
}
```

As pointed in a comment, there are more efficient solutions. Here is one of them, with the drawback that it is a little more complicated:

```js
const list = [2, 3, 4, 5]
const res = 6;

const elems = new Set()
list.forEach(num => {
  if (num == 0 && res == 0) {
    console.log('0 times anything is 0');
  } else if (res%num == 0 && elems.has(res/num)) {
    console.log(num + ' * ' + res/num + ' = ' + res);
  } else {
    elems.add(num);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES 2019.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var result = 6

array.flatMap(
    (v, i) => array.slice(i + 1).map( w => v * w === result && console.log(v, w))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase `performance` significantly, using the given solution. First, `eliminate` unused data then perform find algorithm.

```js
const data = [2, 3, 4, 5];
const find = (data, result) => {
  for (let k = 1; k < data.length; k = k + 1) {
    for (let i = 0, j = data.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
      if (data[i] * data[j] === result) {
        return [data[i], data[j]];
      }
    }
    let temp = data[data.length - 1];
    data[data.length - 1] = data[k];
    data[k] = temp;
  }
};
const findClean = (data, result) => {
  return find(
    data.filter((num) => result % num === 0),
    result
  );
};
console.log("find:" + find(data, 6));
console.log("find:" + find(data, 8));
console.log("find:" + find(data, 10));
console.log("find:" + find(data, 15));

console.log("findClean:" + findClean(data, 6));
console.log("findClean:" + findClean(data, 8));
console.log("findClean:" + findClean(data, 10));
console.log("findClean:" + findClean(data, 15));
```

Comment: i think looks fine...but may want to filter the array if it contains any elements greater than  multiplication result. I am not sure if his array will be only integers or not, but that could change the constraints even further.

Comment: added.. both solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = []
const list = [2, 3, 4, 5];
list.some(n => {
  if (6 % n === 0 && list.includes(6/n)) {
    result = [n, 6/n];
    return true;
  }
})
```